# Authentication scheme missing when adding authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

**Error: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.**

I am creating two applications: WebApi and this work i follow the tutorial: [WebApi Core](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#app-settings-cs)

When running postman, this work great. The issue i have is trying to create asp.net core consuming the web api I am following this tutorial: [Client Side](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/db752e63-8e07-4760-b7f2-a882e67636ce.aspx)

So this is kinda of what I have

Two controller HomeController, AccountController

AccountController

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(AuthenticatedUser user)
        {
            string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

            AuthenticatedUser userModel = new AuthenticatedUser();
            userModel.Username = user.Username;
            userModel.Password = user.Password;

            string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userModel);
            var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/Token", contentData).Result;
            string stringJWT = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JWT jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWT>(stringJWT);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", jwt.Token);

            ViewBag.Message = "User logged in successfully!";

            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

HomeController (nothing special except I added authorize at the start)

```
   [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
...
```

On my startup.cs

ConfigureServices method

```
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();

            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
                   // options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
                });
```

and added a few method in Configure method

```
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

Unsure what I am missing, I installed the following package dont know if i am missing some.

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIDConnect
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

I must say the issue only occurs if i place the attribute [Authorize] on the home controller ( didnt try any other location, but i have a feeling i am missing something to bind the authorize attribute and scheme, but I am not sure).

Comment: As my assumption, HomeController is a Web application, isn't it? And you are trying to retrieve JWT from '/Token' then you save its into Session. In client side, you try to access Home after user got JWT token, right?.

Comment: Yes that correct

Comment: So that you must save this token to Cookie instead of Session because your authentication scheme is Cookie-based. You can prefer this code https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample/blob/master/Controllers/AccountController.cs to make you clearly how to use Cookie and OpenId.

Comment: If i ain't mistaken, you are doing self-JWT in '/Token', right? In practical, JWT is only used to perform Web API by attaching Authorization Header. In web-based scenario, you should use Cookie-based by calling HttpContext.SignInAsync() instead of JWT. But in case you still want to use JWT and Session, you can change options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and use this topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1 with OnMessageReceived event to retrieve a jwt token in your Request.Session

Comment: You are correct "Token" return a generated JWT token that I use for validating when using authorize on the api, and yeah it make sense to use cookie for validation on the client side, i am trying to understand what you send to me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your Client Side, your startup looks ok.

You should use HttpContext.SignInAsync() and store your token using Cookie since your authentication scheme is cookie-based.

So for example, when working with JWT, normally you have claims associated with it. You will need these claims to build up a ClaimsPrincipal object in order to SignIn. See updated code below:

NOTE: NEVER USE ".Result" on async methods. Also, look into using IHttpClientFactory instead of creating an HttpClient directly yourself.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(AuthenticatedUser user)
        {
            // This section should be essentially removed. Use IHttpClientFactory 
            string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

            string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/Token", contentData);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
            {
                string stringJWT = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JWT jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWT>(stringJWT);

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                // This line here fixes your main issue
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);

                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", jwt.Token);

                 ViewBag.Message = "User logged in successfully!";
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Note for deserializing token, you can use this as well:

```
public JwtSecurityToken GetDecodedToken(string token)
{
   return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler( ).ReadJwtToken(token);
}
```